# Anaconda Navigator cannot create new environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I need to use Python at work and just installed Anaconda Navigator today. I am able to open the Navigator GUI without any problems. I am able to open the Create new environment prompt. I fill out the details and hit ok.

Navigator creates a New tab for the environment I requested under the base(root) tab. At the bottom it says: "Creating environment" and there is a blue progress bar and a cancel button. It does this for a while then the new tab disappears and it no longer says creating environment at the bottom and the progress bar is gone.

In the new environment prompt, it tells me where it will save the environment. I have gone to that folder and there is nothing there after the tab disappears.

I am using Anaconda Navigator 1.9.2 on Windows 7 Enterprise. Since I am on my work computer, this is the only version of Anaconda we are allowed to use, so I can't update to the newest version. Although I need python version 2.7, I have tried creating a new environment for version 2.7, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7(which are all of my options) just to see if it works for any of them and it does not. One time the creating environment didn't disappear, but it just kept going for an hour and nothing happened, I was trying python 3.6 at the time.

I was able to load https://api.anaconda.org/, so I don't think my company is blocking the api. It returned this:

```
{
"api_docs_url": "https://api.anaconda.org/docs", 
"brand": "Anaconda Cloud", 
"conda_url": "https://conda.anaconda.org/", 
"main_url": "https://anaconda.org/", 
"ok": 1, 
"pypi_url": "https://pypi.anaconda.org/", 
"swagger_url": "https://api.anaconda.org/swagger.json"
}
```

Comment: What happens when you open an Ancaonda Prompt and do `conda create -n your_env_name python=2.7 anaconda`?

Comment: @Ares It says "CondaError: Solving environment: failed    <new line>    No writable package cache directories found in ('...mypath\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\pkgs', '...mypath\\conda\\conda\\pkgs')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is somewhat resolved. I had two versions installed, so I uninstalled both of them and reinstalled Anaconda once. Now I can create new environments from the command line using the code from @Ares, but Anaconda Navigator won't even open. This is good enough for me for now.

Comment: I disagree, this is not solved, I can't create new environments on a fresh install.

Answer (score 8):

I also had a fresh anaconda-navigator installation on my mac which was not creating a new environment. The following solved the problem

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be late to the party, but for me it helped to run Anaconda Navigator as administrator (in windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I had created a new environment which I called wells, but removed it with "Anaconda Navigator" (wanted to learn more before continuing).
Trying to re-create wells with Navigator failed.

Testing using the command "conda create --name wells" from a powershell gave the error message:
WARNING: A directory already exists at the target location
'C:..my path..\Anaconda3\envs\wells'
but it is not a conda environment.
Continue creating environment (y/[n])?
I responded "n" and removed manually the directory - this to check the Navigator.
That solved my Navigator - create environment - problem.
(i.e. apparently a bug in the Navigator's remove environment function).

Trond

Answer (score 0):

I create an env called my_env_python3.8, then later I delete my_env_python3.8 via anaconda navigator. The anaconda navigator is unable to create a new environment using the name "my_env_python3.8".

solution is go to  ../anaconda3/envs/ the manully delete the folder "my_env_python3.8". After finishing this anaconda navigator was able to start making a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda navigator`s environment creation always has bugs. It is always robust and stable to create env. using CMD within navigator under the (base) env.

`conda create -n name_of_your_env`

Your created environment will appear now on Anaconda navigator after a refresh.