# Jupyter notebook and other application launch issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I have installed anaconda from its official website but I am not able to access launch jupyter notebook or any other application using the anaconda navigator. First, the navigator shows me to install, when I click on the install option it gives me an environment location not found error(check attached image).
after clicking ok on the error, it shows the option to launch but doesn't work, loads for some time and then nothing happens. I can access the jupyter notebook using the command prompt but I wanna know that why its not working through the navigator. Also, I am not able to change the theme of the notebook even after installing jupyterthemes using pip. I wanna that work too.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKN6w.png)the opening page of the navigator

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIrob.png)the error after clicking on launch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda Navigator cannot create new environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270552/anaconda-navigator-cannot-create-new-environment)